# Why can't a typedef type be used to declare its parent class' ctors?

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef, using-directives, using-declaration

```
template<typename>
struct A
{
    int n;

    A(bool)
    {}
};

template<typename>
struct B
{
    struct C : A<B>
    {
        using Base = A<B>;

        using A<B>::A; // ok
        using Base::n; // ok

        // error: dependent using declaration resolved to type without 'typename'
        using Base::A;
    };

    C get() const
    {
        return C(true);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto b = B<int>();
    b.get();
}
```

The error is described in the code.

**Why can't a typedef type be used to declare its parent class' ctors?**

Comment: Note: Works in GCC 9.3 and MSVC v19.24.  Fails in Clang 10.0.0 (adding the `typename` keyword resolves that issue, but Clang has other problems that GCC does not).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar behaviour was earlier [reported](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23107) as a possible Clang bug: *[Bug 23107] Constructor inheritance on template not working correctly*.

Richard Smith's comment on this report:

> The C++ committee have discussed this case and did not intend for that syntax
>   to be valid. Use `using myBase::myBase;` instead to declare an inheriting constructor.

So, you should write `using Base::Base;` instead of `using Base::A;`. After this fix, your code compiles with Clang.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2070 for the corresponding C++ core language issue.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else commented, your code compiles on the latest GCC and MSVC without problems.

Your problem seems to happen on Clang.

The standard has something similar to this naming issue for destructors ([source](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.qual#6)):

> In a qualified-id of the form:
>
> [...] type-name::~type-name
>
> the second type-name is looked up in the same scope as the first.

```cpp
struct C {
  typedef int I;
};
typedef int I1, I2;
extern int* p;
extern int* q;
p->C::I::~I();      // I is looked up in the scope of C
q->I1::~I2();       // I2 is looked up in the scope of the postfix-expression

struct A {
  ~A();
};
typedef A AB;
int main() {
  AB* p;
  p->AB::~AB();     // explicitly calls the destructor for A
}
```

But I couldn't find anything that clear related to constructors. I'd assume the behavior should be the same, but only someone more experienced with the Standard could confirm.

Interestingly enough, if you make your `A` class not a template, it works on Clang as well:

```cpp
struct A
{
    A(bool) {}
};

template<typename>
struct B
{
    struct C : A
    {
        using Base = A;
        using Base::A;
    };
//...
```

So maybe that's a Clang bug?

One thing you can do is use `Base`'s constructor: `Base::Base`:

```cpp
struct C : A<B>
{
    using Base = A<B>;
    using Base::Base;
};
```